# How to setup a project that contains C# files, MySQL and MATLAB files

Tags: c#, mysql, matlab, c#-4.0

I've made a program using C#, a MySQL database and MATLAB M-files. How should I setup a project for them? I need the MATLAB complier.

Comment: We certainly can't help you with a Matlab compiler here.

Answer (score 1):

> I made a program with c sharp and mysql database and matlab m files
>   and wanna make setup project for them how? and need matalb complier

1. You can add any file type to your project. The key is to get the correct combination of "Build Action" and "Copy to Output Directory" to determine what to do with the files. Obviously, your C# files are automatically setup correctly, but your mysql and matlab files aren't.
2. You can use the "Pre-build Event" and "Post-build Event" to do whatever is necessary with your miscellaneous files. For example, you can call into your matlab compiler before your project compiles (or after, however you want).
3. [Matlab Compiler](http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/) -- Go download it from Mathworks.